# How to use a service with bunch of wsdl and xsd files?

Tags: xml, git, xsd, wsdl

I'm trying to develop a flight application. I registered [here](https://developer.travelport.com/).

and watched an introduction video and started. First I saw lots of documentation, a link to git hub and a link to download some files called schema. here it is: [File to download.](https://files.fm/u/7jaeru97)
My last two days has spend to find how to use this schema files to connect to service?
Does anyone has experiences with such services?

This is a link to their application which works. [github](https://github.com/Travelport/travelport-uapi-tutorial-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the README for the repo you linked states you will generate client code using tooling provided by the language vendor.  In the .NET space you can use Visual Studio or svcutil.exe to generate C# or VB.NET client libraries that use Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) to connect to the service.

You will need to configure the ABC of the service (Address, Binding and Contract) either in code or configuration to allow you to connect to the service.

There are lots of getting started tutorials for WCF available via your search engine of choice.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It seems I've found the solution. [This website](https://codewala.net/2013/04/23/wsdl-ans-svcutil-add-web-service-reference-in-vs-20102012/) gave me the hint that it might be an old web service not a WCF service. I'm working on it. Thank you for your response.